# subscribe to changes from modal component in ngx-bootstrap modal

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-modal

I'm launching a modal using `ngx-bootstrap` via `this.modalService.show(ListModalComponent, <options>)` by passing in the component to the modal ([docs link](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-component)). I need to subscribe to an event emitter in the component to act on change events from inside the modal but I am unable to get a reference to the component because it doesn't exist before the modal is shown. What is the recommended approach?

Here's a Plunkr with [my current setup](https://plnkr.co/edit/9tdZCDEqgaRJ2ZGwNSUt?p=preview). Please see `app.component.ts` line 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to this event after calling `.show()` like this `this.bsModalRef.content.listUpdates.subscribe({...})`

Also, you can create a shared service and inject it in both components, and use this event instead of an internal event of modal.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize I would have access to `content`

Comment: this.bsModalRef.content.updateFunction.subcribe is not a function.... I console content inside this.bsModalRef.content ( i found there is updateFuntion).... I am using angular 9.1.3....... I set up output() property correctly inside child component